# Is this observation about the Borel Hierarchy trivial?

Tags: lo.logic, borel-sets, descriptive-set-theory

Hello, consider the following theorem.  Is it trivial?  Is it interesting?  Is it worth including in a paper if I can prove it in 1 line as a corollary?

Theorem:  Suppose $n>0$ is a natural.  Suppose
$S=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\cap_{j\in\mathbb{N}}X_{ij}=
\cap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\cup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}Y_{ij}$, where the $X_{ij},Y_{ij}$ are $\Delta_n^0$ subsets of Baire space.  Then there exists a single family $Z_{ij}$ of $\Delta_n^0$ subsets of Baire space such that
$S=\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\cap_{j\in\mathbb{N}}Z_{ij}=\cap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\cup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}Z_{ij}$.

Edit:  Forgot to mention, I'm talking about boldface pointclasses here.

Comment: Aren't $\Delta^0_n$ sets closed under countable unions and intersections?

Comment: @Andres: No.  `$\Delta^0_1$` (boldface) is clopen.  

Comment: Andreas: Oh, of course.

Comment: Well, I ended up adding it.  If anybody wants to see the proof, here is the paper, the corollary is at the very end:  http://www.math.osu.edu/~alexander/lopsided.pdf